# How to reliably set umask on Ubuntu 19.10? SOLVED (for 20.04&20.10 also)

Tags: umask

I have set up a new computer running Ubuntu 19.10. Now I want to set default permissions to be more restrictive via umask, but fail to do so.

I tried setting umask with every advice I could find here and elsewhere:

- /etc/login.defs
- /etc/adduser.conf
- /etc/default/login
- /etc/pam.d/login
- /etc/pam.d/common-session
- $HOME/.profile
- chfn --other umask=027

Nothing works so far. After rebooting I still get 022. I managed to get bash adjusted via $HOME/.bashrc

Since I also have troubles with default openjdk and clamav, I got really frustrated at this point. I cannot remember ever having so much issues with Ubuntu like now.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue solved on a Ubuntu 20.04 machine by adding 'umask=' to /etc/passwd manually.

Further information can be found in the manpage passwd.5